Django queryset count with zero
I have this Django Model :
class Survey(models.Model):

    call = models.OneToOneField(Call, null=True, related_name='survey', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='survey', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    when_start = models.DateTimeField()
    when_end = models.DateTimeField()

I would like to obtain the number of calls per service over a time slot
I tried this :
start = datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 17, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 17, 23, 59, 59)
services = <QuerySet [<Service: S1>, <Service: S2>, <Service: S3>]>

Survey.objects.filter(service__in=services, when_start__range=(start, end)).values('service__name').annotate(nb=Count('call'))

result : <QuerySet [{'service__name': 'S1', 'nb': 50}, {'service__name': 'S2', 'nb': 119}]>

But I would like to have this (0 for "S3" service):
<QuerySet [{'service__name': 'S1', 'nb': 50}, {'service__name': 'S2', 'nb': 119}, {'service__name': 'S3', 'nb': 0}]]>

I read several notes that referred to "Coalesce" but I can't seem to use it correctly

Annotate the service instead:
from django.db.models import Count, Q

services.objects.annotate(
    nb=Count('survey__call', filter=Q(survey__when_start__range=(start, end)))
)
You also get Service objects with an attribute .nb, so not only the name of the Service.

Thanks. But with filter on the day : services.annotate(nb=Count('survey__call'), filter=Q(survey__when_start__range=(start, end))), I get :
<QuerySet [<Service: S1 (nb=1)>, <Service: S1 (nb=1)>, <Service: S1 (nb=2)>, <Service: S2 (nb=1)>, <Service: S2 (nb=1)>, <Service: S2 (nb=2)>, <Service: S3 (nb=1)>, <Service: S3 (nb=2)>]>
Survey.objects.filter(service__name="S3", when_start__range=(start, end)).count() => 0

@Aurélien: you don't use other .annotates in the services? Can you show where services originates from? What is the query used?

for test, I use this : services = Service.objects.filter(name__in=("S1", "S2", "S3")). Survey.objects.filter(service__in=services, when_start__range=(start, end)).count() => 169. Survey.objects.filter(service__name="S1", when_start__range=(start, end)).count() => 50. Survey.objects.filter(service__name="S2", when_start__range=(start, end)).count() => 119. Survey.objects.filter(service__name="S3", when_start__range=(start, end)).count() => 0. services.annotate(nb=Count('survey__call'), filter=Q(survey__when_start__range=(start, end))).count() => 45016

@Aurélien: I think I got it, the filterin gis survey__when=..., apparently the survey__ was stuck in my keyboard.

is it work?
objs = Survey.objects.filter(when_start__range=(start, end))
a = objs.filter(service={service}).values('service__name').annotate(nb=Count('call'))
b = objs.filter(service={service1}).values('service__name').annotate(nb=Count('call'))
...
z = objs.filter(service={service3}).values('service__name').annotate(nb=Count('call'))

result = a|b|...|z

